# How can I set Joomla! to point to index.php by default?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5

I have this issue in joomla where typing mydomain.com won't pull the website, I have to specify mydomain.com/index.php I must have done something silly, would anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've adjusted your server settings (apache?), and the server is defaulting to using index.html if nothing is specified.  Joomla uses an empty index.html file in most folders for security, so you'll need have your server default to index.php instead.

If you *are* using Apache, check the config (httpd.conf?), and change it to something like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm default.htm
```

It occurred to me that you may not be able to change your apache config, so you can do it via htaccess instead:  Create a text file called .htaccess containing that same line, and put it into your Joomla home directory.  If you already have a .htaccess file there, be sure to add this command to the end of the file.

Comment: it's doing it on the IP level as well thought, so ipnumber/sitename won't load the website I have to do ipnumber/sitename/index.php

Comment: It's your web server, not the dns or ip......apache doesn't know it's supposed to load index.php...you have make the string change so that apache will do that